# nodejs response compression advice

Tags: node.js, nginx, gzip, scalability

I have written an API server using NodeJS. It's basically a REST server, that exposes some commands whose responses are the result of one or several database queries. The final JSON is sent to the client. Nothing very original.

I'd like to implement response compression, as the typical `Content-length` is 5-20kb of (json) text, that once compressed goes down to 1-5kb.

Expecting a moderate to big load, I have a dilemma: Having read lots of documents about NodeJS weaknesses if the (only) thread is blocked with computational expensive functions, I don't know if:

a) Do not implement compression at all, "after all, 20kb is not that much and maybe keeping things ultra-simple may be better"

b) Implement GZIP compression using the ZLIB NodeJS module, which allows to asynchronously compress the response. Then I'll be adding overhead where it hurts, but the response size will be cut to 1/4.

c) Proxy NodeJS through NGINX and configure NGIX to compress the response. This seems the best of both worlds, but I don't know if the CPU + socket + memory overhead of NGINX (in the same hardware) will be worse than (a) or even (b)

What do you think?

Comment: The challenge here is that you haven't explained what strong motivation or reasoning you have for implementing the compression so without understanding that, we can't really participate in the tradeoff involved in whether to implement it or not.  In general, you should not add complication (e.g. compression) to your implementation or deployment unless you are sure such complication is a net win.  So, the core question seems to be what is the main reason for implementing compression in the first place?  20k isn't exactly big to start with (teeny compared to most images served to a web page).

Comment: Well, my motivation is that I'm scared of locking NodeJS's only thread and waste precious time just GZipping as the number of requests/sec grow. But on the other hand, compression will cut the response size by 3/4, and that's something that is really interesting too. 20-30Kb may not seem that much for a single response, but the idea is to deliver  hundreds of requests / sec. I'm just interested in the "best practice" opinion from somebody with experience with production servers on NodeJS, I come from the traditional Java world and am used to proxies like apache/nginx/etc that do the dirty work

Comment: I, personally wouldn't mess with the extra computation of compression until you know you have a bandwidth usage issue that justifies the added development and scalability testing.  You may end up with much more important things to work on once you get launched and under high load.  Much better to launch without compression and then decide where best to deploy your extra dev resources after you  have operating experience.

Comment: cool :) thanks for your valuable comments

Comment: FYI, on a multi-core server, when the time comes you can cluster node.js to use more of the CPU available to you if you end up needing/wanting that.

Comment: yeah, I tuned the server to spawn as many workers as  `require('os').cpus().length`, my current servers are dual core, so it didn't make any sense to have one of the cores sleeping